# Объясните на русском языке как работает mapStateToProps в React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Объясните пожалуйста подробно как работает mapStateToProps в React Redux.

Читаю на оф. сайте на английском и не могу понять, как оно точно работает.

---

Как я понимаю(скорее всего не правильно) функция принимает состояние(state) компонента и передает его в хранилище(store) тем самым обновляя store?

Comment: mapStateToProps, обратите внимание как называется функция. В ней нет слова component => она этого не делает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно просто. Помните [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment) современного JavaScript? Используя этот синтаксис мы можем присвоить только нужные нам поля объекта.

```
function test({a, b, c}) {
    console.log(a, b, c); // 1, 2, 3
}

test({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}); // d игнорируется
```

Тут по аналогии - мы избегаем полного дублирования состояния компоненту, выделяя только нужные нам поля

```
function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    return {
        visible: !(state.login && state.password),
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch) {
    return {
        login: (login, password) => dispatch({type: ActionType.Login, login, password}),
    };
}
export const LoginDialog = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Internal.LoginDialog);
```

Так же, мы можем выразить prop для компонента исходя из нескольких свойств состояния, например, диалог авторизации показывается тогда, когда приложению неизвестны логин и пароль. При этом, сами логин и пароль он точно не знает.

И *mapStateToProps*, и *mapDispatchToProps* работают по направлению **к компоненту** от состояния. Для обновления состояния используется *dispatch*.

Comment: Пётр большое спасибо за ответ!